How to best print a stacked object?
I would like to print several identical objects (let's say a ring, to set things up)
Instead of printing each one separately, I would like to stack them (in this case - in a cylinder).
My question: how to best do this in order to be able to detach them from each other?
Should I add short rods between them (along the circumference), tightly packed (to balance the support part on one hand, and the "ability to break" on the other). Or are there standard ways to approach that?

An identical question can be found here.

Thank you @0scar, I flagged it as duplicate

Perfect, thanks!
